# FB with FB_Init cannot be a return type

Tags: types, return, codesys

Codesys 3.5.16.70

There appears to be no way to return a type of function block if the function block has an FB_Init method. Please see the image below for a simple contrived example. I can return a reference to the function block but I would like to pass the function block type.

The purpose for doing this is, I am configuring the function block and need a temporary copy which I would place in the model of an MVC pattern (not shown in the screen shot below.) The temporary copy is what I configure until the operator saves the configuration at which time the function block is copied back to the original. This, of course, requires a function block return type.

I have thought about putting all the data of the FB in a structure and passing that but it seems an extra step, but maybe that is necessary? I cannot pass an interface of the POU as an interface is essentially a reference to the original object.

Am I missing some key element to the language that would allow me to do this simply, or is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

[image: FB with FB_Init as return type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't think you can return a Function Block from a Method (and Property) with a `FB_Init` Method since Function Blocks need to always be initialized (unless `{attribute 'noinit'}` is used, which doesn't seem to work with Method/Property return types).

Your options are:

1. Return a Reference/Pointer to the Function Block and make a copy locally in the caller:

```pascal
fb_ref: REFERENCE TO FB;
fb_ptr: POINTER TO FB;
{attribute 'noinit'}
fb_copy: FB;

fb_ref := InternalFBRef;
fb_copy := fb_ref;

fb_ptr := InternalFBPtr;
fb_copy := fb_ptr^;
```

2. Box the Function Block copy in a Structure:

```pascal
TYPE BOXED_FB :
STRUCT
    {attribute 'noinit'}
    fb: FB;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

fb_box: BOXED_FB ;
{attribute 'noinit'}
fb_copy: FB;

fb_box := InternalFBBox;
fb_copy := fb_box.fb;
```

3. Return an Interface that gives you methods to configure the Function Block dirrectly.
4. What you seem to be trying to do sounds simmilar to the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). Maybe see if doing it that way is more usefull, or perhaps another [OOP design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) is more apropriate here?

Comment: Thanks Guiorgy. I'm not trying to create a new type really, I'm just trying to modify the contents of an existing object in a way that can be cancelled so no modifications are performed on the original object if needed - so the factory pattern probably wouldn't help me in this case. Your mention of a boxed function block is similar to what I had in mind but with a bit of a twist which I like. I may use the 2nd solution. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Hi Guiorgy, I am currently implementing a factory pattern and I am tempted to go for the first proposed solution. I have a method CreateX that returns a reference to an FB X. The instance of X is created as a VAR_TEMP in that method, and the reference points to that TEMP. The returned REFERENCE TO X is then copied locally. Is this dangerous to do?

Comment: @CédricMoers As per the Stackoverflow rules please create a separate question, so others can find the question and help you more easily. Comments aren't designed for that.